# regex in preg_match_all() doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

I have the following string:

```
"<h2>Define Vim is the greatest</h2> word processor, good <h3>Vi</h3>!".
```

I want to select `h2` and `h3` like the following structure with a regex.

Expected output would be:

```
array(
    0   =>  <h2>Define Vim is the greatviest</h2>
    1   =>  <h3>Vi</h3>
)
```

So I implement my regular expression as follow:

```
preg_match_all("/(?:<h2>|<h3>).*vi.*(?:<\/h2>|<\/h3>)/i", $input, $matches)
```

But instead of the desirable result as above, it outputs the following result.

Current output:

```
array(
    0 => <h2>Define Vim is the greatviest</h2> word prviocessor ever created <h3>Vi</h3>
)
```

How can I change my code/regex, so I get the tags as in the expected output above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your problem is, that you first missing the [delimiters for your regex](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and second `vi` is case-sensitive, so you would have to add the [`i` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), for case-insensitivity.

So your code could look something like this (Just removed the vi in the regex and now I just grab everything between `h1-6` tags):

```
<?php

    $input = '"<h2>Define Vim is the greatest</h2> word processor, good <h3>Vi</h3>!".';

    preg_match_all("/(?:<h[0-6]>).*?(?:<\/h[0-6]>)/", $input, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <h2>Define Vim is the greatest</h2>
            [1] => <h3>Vi</h3>
        )

)
```

**EDIT:**

As from your updated regex now your problem is, that `.*` is greedy, means it takes as much as it can. To make it non-greedy you have to add a `?` at the end. So just change your `.*` -> `.*?`.

Comment: Sorry I wrote my regular expression on phpliveregex.com. So I forgot to put delimiters and case-insensitive flags when I wrote the sample code for the question. These are already included in original code. Edited. :)

Comment: @Steve.NayLinAung Then your problem is, that `.*` is greedy, means it takes as much as it can. To make it non-greedy, just apply a `?` at the end. So `.*` -> `.*?`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks, you right. I forgot greedy problem. Actually I want h2 and h3 which included "vi" text. Yes, I missed to describe in the question. Now I get my desirable result with this expression "/(?:<h[2-3]>).*?vi.*?(?:<\/h[2-3]>)/i".